# NEMA 17 motor not turning

Tags: stepper-motor, multimeter

I just bought a [NEMA 17 motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B38GX54H) and some [DRV2285 drivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NCE3ZW1) and am following [this tutorial](https://lastminuteengineers.com/drv8825-stepper-motor-driver-arduino-tutorial/).

Originally, the problem was that the stepper motors weren't turning, only vibrating. I was able to adjust the voltage using a multimeter. Now, all my voltage values are reading zero from the motor driver. I verified that my multimeter wasn't the culprit by checking my 12 V, 2 A power supply that I'm using to power my driver. Now, the stepper motor won't turn too. How do I get my stepper motor  working? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I am using:

```c
// Include the AccelStepper Library
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// Define pin connections
const int dirPin = 5;
const int stepPin = 4;

// Define motor interface type
#define motorInterfaceType 1

// Creates an instance
AccelStepper myStepper(motorInterfaceType, stepPin, dirPin);

void setup() {
    // set the maximum speed, acceleration factor,
    // initial speed and the target position
    myStepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);
    myStepper.setAcceleration(50);
    myStepper.setSpeed(200);
    myStepper.moveTo(200);
}

void loop() {
    // Change direction once the motor reaches target position
    if (myStepper.distanceToGo() == 0) 
        myStepper.moveTo(-myStepper.currentPosition());

    // Move the motor one step
    myStepper.run();
}
```

I am using the wiring shown in the article I linked above, except my DIR pin is in pin 5, and my STEP pin is in pin 4 because pins two and three are being used:

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: Why have you defined the pins as 4 and 5 but connected 2 and 3?

Comment: Red green yellow blue is unusual for a stepper. All of mine are red blue green black. Maybe your wires are mixed up? Can you use a multimeter to check the DC resistance of each pair of wires? If your wiring's right, measuring red and green should be less than 10 ohms.

Comment: My wires are red blue green black too. The diagram on the website just says red green yellow blue. I used a multimeter and switched the two middle wires(blue and green) after the motor stopped vibrating all together. Now I think I have the correct wiring, but the motor will not turn in any wiring configuration. Did I blow my motor? I tested all five of my drivers and none of them make the motor vibrate anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning, I changed the driver and it worked!

Comment: Did you change anything else from your original setup? Your previous comment implied that you already tried changing drivers.

Comment: _"I tested all five of my drivers and none of them make the motor vibrate anymore."_ Are you saying that all of those 5 drivers were damaged, and the existing setup with a new driver worked? If so, can you explain what could have damaged those drivers?

Comment: I did try using 24V at 4A on some of them, which may have damaged them. I also accidentally shorted out some of the pins when trying to adjust the potentiometer with a screwdriver. These were also cheap drivers, so that could have played a part. One of them had a hole in the chip and started smoking...